# Woher kommt die schweizerdeutsche Verstärkung "huren..."?

Tags: etymology, dialect, colloquial, swiss-german

In der Schweiz hört man oft Wörter wie *hurenkalt* oder *hurengut*. Dabei verstärkt die Vorsilbe *huren* die Bedeutung des Adjektives. Ein Äquivalent wäre die Vorsilbe *sau* im Deutschen. Woher kommt diese Wendung? Hat sie etwas mit dem Wort für Prostituierte zu tun oder ist sie anderen Ursprungs?

Google liefert mir hier erwartungsgemäß keine seriösen Antworten. ;)

Comment: Ich darf nicht vergessen, nach meinen Google-Recherchen meine Such-Historie zu löschen. Käme gegenüber meiner Frau etwas in Erklärungsnot "schweiz huren..."

Comment: @splattne: wieso denn?  Einfach auf diese Frage zeigen, und gut ist.  Sollte jedenfalls so sein, oder vertraut dir deine Frau so wenig? ;-)

Comment: I don't think Jurgen is married if he thinks it's so easy to talk your way out of that one.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Im [Mundartlexikon des Schweizer Rundfunks steht](http://www.drs.ch/www/de/drs/161151.huere-guet.html):

> **huere guet**
>   sehr gut, ausserordentlich gut

Mit der Erklärung:

> Das huere im Usdruck huere guet chunt vom Wort Huer mit dr Bedütig «gefallene Frau, Prostituierte» häär. Es isch eis vo dene Wörter, wo zeige, wi ugliich Maa u Frou i dr dütsche Schpraach behandlet wäärde, wius für e Maa ke vergliichbaari Bezeichnig git.
>
> Das Wort chunt scho im Authoochdütsche voor u isch en Ableitig vo huor mit dr Bedütig «ausserehelicher Beischlaf oder Ehebruch». Luschtigerwiis geit ds latinische Wort carus mit dr Bedütig «lieb, wert, teuer» u daa dermit o Caritas uf di gliichi Wortwüürze zrügg wi Huer.

Ich übersetze (Hervorhebungen von mir):

> Das *huere* [huren] im Ausdruck *huere guet* [hurengut] hat seinen **Ursprung** vom Wort *Huer* **[Hure]** mit der Bedeutung «gefallene Frau, Prostituierte». Es ist eines jener Wörter, die zeigen, wie ungleich Mann und Frau in der deutschen Sprache behandelt werden, weil es für einen Mann keine vergleichbare Bezeichnung gibt.
>
> Das Wort kommt schon im Althochdeutschen vor und ist eine Ableitung von *huor* mit der Bedeutung «ausserehelicher Beischlaf oder Ehebruch». Lustigerweise geht das lateinische Wort *carus* mit der Bedeutung «lieb, wert, teuer» und somit auch *Caritas* auf die gleiche Wortwurzel zurück wie Hure.

Im selben Eintrag steht weiters, dass es zunächst übertragen als wüstes Schimpfwort verwendet wurde. Aber schon im 19. Jh. hat man vor Haupt- und Eigenschaftswörtern als reines **Verstärkungswort** im Sinne von *"sehr"* **ohne negative Bedeutung** verwendet — ähnlich wie im deutschen umgangssprachlichen *"verdammt"* wie in *"verdammt schön"*.

Deshalb kann z. B. jemand ein *"huere Glückpiuz"* ("Hurensglückspilz") sein und ein *"huere Glück"* haben. Es gibt auch noch die stärkere Variante: *"uhuere"*.

Die Geschichte, dass *huere* etwas mit *"hurra"* zu tun haben soll, stimmt übrigens nicht.

---

Interessant ist auch, dass das Wort anscheinend in letzter Zeit vermehrt im Schweizerdeutschen verwendet wird, wie der Autor in [diesem Artikel der Weltwoche](http://www.weltwoche.ch/ausgaben/2003-31/artikel-2003-31-huere-primitiv.html) behauptet:

> Was ist mit unserem Schweizerdeutsch passiert? Wieso brauchen wir immer mehr hochdeutsche und englische Fremdwörter, wenn wir doch aus dem eigenen reichen Wortschatz schöpfen könnten? Und wird unsere Sprache nicht immer eintöniger?
>
> Huere chalt, huere nass, huere schön, huere primitiv. Was einst als uhuere ein erdiges bündnerisches oder walliserdeutsches Verstärkungswort war, hat sich ebenso epidemieartig ausgebreitet wie das teutonische Scheisse. Wo bist du geblieben, altehrwürdiger Schiissdräck?

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese wieder einmal ausführliche und vollständige Antwort!

Comment: @Deve Danke für die netten Worte. Dass ich seit meiner Kindheit das Schweizer Fernsehen empfange, war sehr nützlich für diese Antwort.

Comment: Interessant wäre zu wissen, ob das niederländische Verb _huren_ mit der Bedeutung _mieten_ englisch _to hire_ (etwa Autos oder Wohnungen) hiermit verwandt ist.

Comment: @bernd_k so wie im Deutschen "anheuern". Keine Ahnung — die Ähnlichkeit könnte auch nur ein Zufall sein.

Comment: _Es gibt auch noch die stärkere Variante: "uhuere"._ Von der Bedeutung her ist dieses Wort identisch mit "huere". Stärker ist es deshalb weil "u" ebenfalls dazu verwendet wird, die Bedeutung eine Adjektivs zu verstärken. z.B. "es isch u kalt".

Comment: Auf ein Zitat aus der ultrarechten Kampfpresse würde ich persönlich ja verzichten.

Comment: @Lukas das erinnert an (niederdeutsch?) "urst kalt", scheinbar das supremum von "ur-". Zu *anheuern* vergleich *anwerben*, wobei *werben* in der Form recht spät in Texten auftaucht. Fällt mir nur ein wegen der Parallele von "Uranus" und dessen alternativer Form "Worsanos". Vgl. "Kriegstrommel *rühren*" mit *wirbeln*, welches Pfeifer mit *werben* vergleicht, sowie En. *war*, De. *wirr*. That's *well* odd, *very* odd.

Answer (score 16):

http://www.mittelschulvorbereitung.ch/content_new/msvDE/Div21bBerndeutsch.pdf

auch interessant zu wissen:

> Das Wort HUERE, das man hierzulande oft als verbale (und
>   nicht eben salonfähige) Verstärkung hört, hat mit einer Prostituierten
>   nur wenig Zusammenhang. Im vorletzten Jahrhundert war „ungeheuer“ in
>   den Alpen ein Modewort, insbesondere im Wallis. Dort tönte es so:
>   (etwas war) üghüüre güet. Als dann 1913 der Lötschbergtunnel eröffnet
>   wurde, kamen die Berner den Wallisern näher, hörten dieses „üghüere
>   güet“ immer wieder und verballhornten es schlussendlich in
>   „huereguet“. Der Kontakt war gegenseitig befruchtend: Heute sagt man
>   im Wallis auch hüeregüet!

Answer (score 4):

*huere guet* chunnt miner Meinig von:

> uhuere guet

uf hochdutsch:

*huere guet* kommt meiner Meinung von:

> ungeheuerlich gut

Answer (score 2):

Meine Theorie:
Das Wort *uhuere/uhuäre* [CH] bedeutet in etwa *ungeheuer* [D], respektive es hat die gleichen Wurzeln.

Begründung:
Norwegisch, welches sehr eng mit Deutsch verwandt ist, kennt das Wort *uhyre* [NO] (in etwa als *ühüre* ausgesprochen) ([Bokmålordboka](http://www.nob-ordbok.uio.no/perl/ordbok.cgi?begge=%20&ordbok=bokmaal&s=n&alfabet=n&renset=j&OPP=uhyre)). Das Wort kann als Nomen benutzt werden und bedeutet dann *Ungeheuer* [D]. Oder es wird als Adjektiv oder Adverb gebraucht mit der Bedeutung *ungeheuer* [D], also als Verstärkungswort genau wie *sehr*.

Im Norwegischen gibt es auch noch das Wort *uhyrlig* [NO] mit der Bedeutung *ungeheuerlich* [D], also im Sinne von *absurd* („Eine ungeheuerliche Anschuldigung“).

Comment: Norwegisch würde ich viel nennen, aber »sehr eng mit Deutsch verwandt« geht mir doch deutlich zu weit …

Comment: das Wort Hure selbst bedeutet letztendlich wohl *teuerste, geliebte*. Kurios! Vgl. auch *hehr (hehre Ziele)*? Die in der Frage angesprochene ansteigende Verwendung dürfte wohl aber doch augenzwinkernd an "Huren(sohn)" angelehnt sein, oder nicht?

Answer (score 1):

Das Wort 'huere' kommt aus dem Alt-Appenzellischen und hat absolut nichts mit Prostitution zu tun! Es stammt vom deutschen Wort 'horrend' ab. So macht das dann auch Sinn... ;-)

Comment: Hast Du dazu einen Referenz? Ich dachte immer, dass *horrend* vom lateinischen *horrere* abstammt. Dass das auch in der Alt-Appenzellerischen Mundart so sein soll, erscheint mir wenig wahrscheinlich.